# import content of php file into a php variable

Tags: php

I have an external php file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>...
...
<body>

<p><?php echo $content;?></p>
..
```

AND in my code:

```
$content = 'sample text';
$body = include("layout/mailtemplate.php");
```

You can see it has php and html code (and pass `$content` outside of file to included file)

Is there any way to store content of this file to a php variable?
(here content of $body is "1"!)

Also I test

```
$body = file_get_contents('layout/mailtemplate.php');
```

It works, but I could not pass `$content` to file.

(I know I could pass it via GET) but I have a lot of variables. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There's a number of templating engines for PHP. `file_get_contents` obtains file's contents as a string, doesn't evaluate the code, you would then need to parse it to replace the necessary parts of it with your contents. `include` will evaluate the contents, but doesn't return a string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You need to use output buffering for that:

```
ob_start();
$content = 'sample text';
include("inc.php");
$body = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

var_dump($body); // string(11) "sample text"
```